# Three way pivot table get all teams a user belongs to and the roles for each team

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot, relationship

I am using a belongsToMany relationship between users, teams, and the roles tables.

What I want to do is query all teams that an authenticated user belongs too and get all of the roles the user has for that team under. Then I want to output the it to JSON. (I'm not using blade).

**User Frank**:

Team 1:

- Manager
- Player

Team 2:

- Manager

Team 5:

- Player

## Query output to show relations

*note: this query is to show the relations for the response*
`return User::first(1)->with('teams','roles')->get();`

**Output:**

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "username":"Frank",
   "name":"Frank",
   "email":"frank@example.com",
   "teams":[  
      {  
         "id":21,
         "name":"Team 1",
         "pivot":{  
            "user_id":1,
            "team_id":21,
            "role_id": 1
         }
      },
      {  
         "id":1,
         "name":"Team 2",
         "pivot":{  
            "user_id":1,
            "team_id":1,
            "role_id":1
         }
      },
      {  
         "id":3,
         "name":"Team 5",
         "pivot":{  
            "user_id":1,
            "team_id":3
            "role_id":2
         }
      }
   ],
   "roles":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "name":"Manager",
         "pivot":{  
            "user_id":1,
            "role_id":1,
            "team_id":21
         }
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "name":"Player",
         "pivot":{  
            "user_id":1,
            "role_id":2,
            "team_id":21
      },
      {  
         "id":1,
         "name":"Manager",
         "pivot":{  
            "user_id":1,
            "role_id":1,
            "team_id":1
         }
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "name":"Player",
         "pivot":{  
            "user_id":1,
            "role_id":2,
            "team_id":3
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

**Edit

[According to this post on laravel.io, it seems there is an outdated package for this very purpose that only works with Laravel 4](https://laravel.io/forum/08-06-2014-three-way-pivot-table-with-eloquent)

> ## Scenario 2
>
> For every user I want to know in which teams they are and what roles they fulfill in that specific team: users->team->roles

Answer (score 0):

add following method to User model:

```php
public function getRolesAttribute(){
   return $this->with('teams.roles')->teams->pluck('roles.name')->flatten()->unique()->toArray();
}
```

now if you retrieve user's roles like `User::first()->roles` it must return an array of role names.

good luck

Comment: >Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$teams

Comment: have you defined `teams()` method on User model ?